# sending results to sheet 2 in row with matched name VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with a bit of code that takes generated values and sends them to sheet2 in the row with the matched name but if those cells are populated move on to the next 3 columns.

[image]

Comment: does Test's infos block always start on the 'F' column?

Comment: what code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

To make your task a little easier to read and less code intensive, I would change your Sheet2 layout, see picture. If you keep your current format the code will need to be more advanced, but this is a start. 
[image: My suggested layout change]

To assign the below code to `Button1`, right click the button and select `Assign Macro`. Copy and paste the macro. when you activate `Button1`, the current Date is added to the first empty cell in Row1, Then the "Expected" and "Actual" values are added to the cells below the date. When you update those values in `Sheet1` and activate the button again, the macro will shift to the next column, etc.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

Dim lCol As Long
lCol = ws2.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    With ThisWorkbook
        ws2.Cells(1, lCol + 1) = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy")
        ws2.Cells(2, lCol + 1) = ws1.Cells(11, 3).Value
        ws2.Cells(3, lCol + 1) = ws1.Cells(11, 3).Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you GMac will test now